# Crowd Flower Integration

Tags: api

We have a requirement that when ever some one click pic in salesforce1 app it will be saved in amazon s3. but first it will go to the crowd flower for reviewing. can anyone suggest best way to integrate. i am trying it but getting http 301 status.

Comment: The first thing to do is look at the "Location" header that will be in the response when you get the 301 status code (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301). If that makes sense, make your request to that URL instead.

Comment: Can you provide your code snippet? For what request are you getting a 301?